# PHP: Call to a member function .... on a non-object

Tags: php

hello I'm having trouble with:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    $role = $this->getFirstRole();

    if ($role->getRoleId() == "admin")
        return true;

    return false;
}
```

it causes: Call to a member function getRoleId() on a non-object

please guys, help. thanks

classes:

```
class Role implements HierarchicalRoleInterface
{
/**
 * Store id.
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * Store role kind.
 * Possible user kinds: 'guest' (not signed in),
  'user' (default for signed in user), 'admin'.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255,
               unique=true, nullable=true)
 */
protected $roleId;

/**
 * Store role parent for inheritance measure.
 * @var Role
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User\Entity\Role")
 */
protected $parent;

/**
 * Get id.
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id.
 * @param int $id
 * @return void
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = (int)$id;
}

/**
 * Get role kind.
 * @return string
 */
public function getRoleId()
{
    return $this->roleId;
}

/**
 * Set role kind.
 * @param string $roleId
 * @return void
 */
public function setRoleId($roleId)
{
    $this->roleId = (string) $roleId;
}

/**
 * Get parent role
 * @return Role
 */
public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * Set parent role.
 * @param Role $parent
 * @return void
 */
public function setParent(Role $parent)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}
}
```

---

```
class User implements UserInterface, ProviderInterface
{
/**
 * Store id.
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Store username.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
protected $username;

/**
 * Store email.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true,  length=255)
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * Store displayName.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50, nullable=true)
 */
protected $displayName;

/**
 * Store password.
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=128)
 */
protected $password;

/**
 * Store state.
 * @var int
 */
protected $state;

/**
 * Store mark.
 * @var float
 */
protected $mark;

/**
 * Store roles collection.
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Role")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_roles",
 *      joinColumns={
            @ORM\JoinColumn(
                name="user_id",
                referencedColumnName="id"
            )
        },
 *      inverseJoinColumns={
            @ORM\JoinColumn(
                name="role_id",
                referencedColumnName="id"
            )
        }
 * )
 */
protected $roles;

/**
 * Store albums collection
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Album\Entity\Album", mappedBy="user",
                  cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $albums;

/**
 * Store comments collection.
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment\Entity\Comment", mappedBy="user",
                  cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $comments;

/**
 * Store marks collection.
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Mark\Entity\Mark", mappedBy="user",
                  cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $marks;

/**
 * Initialies collections.
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->albums = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->comments = new ArrayCollection();
    $this->marks = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Get id.
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set id.
 * @param int $id
 * @return void
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = (int) $id;
}

/**
 * Get username.
 * @return string
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return htmlspecialchars($this->username);
}

/**
 * Set username.
 * @param string $username
 * @return void
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * Get email.
 * @return string
 */
public function getEmail()
{
    return $this->email;
}

/**
 * Set email.
 * @param string $email
 * @return void
 */
public function setEmail($email)
{
    $this->email = $email;
}

/**
 * Get displayName.
 * @return string
 */
public function getDisplayName()
{
    return $this->displayName;
}

/**
 * Set displayName.
 * @param string $displayName
 * @return void
 */
public function setDisplayName($displayName)
{
    $this->displayName = $displayName;
}

/**
 * Get password.
 * @return string
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set password.
 * @param string $password
 * @return void
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}

/**
 * Get state.
 * @return int
 */
public function getState()
{
    return $this->state;
}

/**
 * Set state.
 * @param int $state
 * @return void
 */
public function setState($state)
{
    $this->state = $state;
}

/**
 * Get roles collection.
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}


public function getFirstRole() {
    $roles = $this->getRoles();
    $firstRole = $roles[0];
    return $firstRole;
}

/**
 * Get comments collection.
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getComments()
{
    return $this->comments;
}

/**
 * Get marks collection.
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getMarks()
{
    return $this->marks;
}

/**
 * Add a role to user.
 * @param Role $role
 * @return void
 */
public function addRole($role)
{
    $this->roles[] = $role;
}

/**
 * Get albums.
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getAlbums()
{
    return $this->albums;
}

public function isAdmin(){
    $role = $this->getFirstRole();
    if ($role->getRoleId() == "admin")
        return true;

    return false;
}

/**
 * Calculate user mark.
 * @return float
 */
public function mark()
{
    if (!$this->mark) {
        $albums = $this->getAlbums();
        $result = 0;
        foreach ($albums as &$album) {
            $result += $album->mark();
        }
        $this->mark = $result;
    }
    return $this->mark;
}
}
```

anyone?
(writing this becaue it says my post is mostly code)
(writing this becaue it says my post is mostly code)

Comment: `$roles[0]` in `getFirstRole()` (from `getRoles()`) is not an object. Where do you define `$this->roles`?

Comment: `getRoleId()` is this a function of your class?

Comment: yeah, i see. how to change this? sorry for dumb question, but i'm such a beginner

Comment: @user3333854 It depends.. The problem is that `$this->roles` should an array full of class instances (with the `getRoleId()` function), but it isn't. What does `var_dump($this->roles)` output? Can you add it to OP?

Comment: @AwladLiton class added :) could you help?

Comment: @h2ooooooo it's not an array, this is Doctrine, Doctrine generates proxy classes and instead of arrays it uses Collection objects

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yeah, I [noticed](http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html) and +1'd you about a minute ago ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems that `$this->getFirstRole()` returned user role as string. you just need to compare it as string.

try this:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    $role = $this->getFirstRole();

    return $role == "admin" ? true : false;

}
```

Comment: `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User\Entity\Role")` role is an entitiy.. so getFirstRole should return an object, `instanceof User\Entity\Role`.

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Get roles collection.
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}
```

Collections are not accessed by `[0]`, they are `Collection` **objects**, use like this:

```
public function getFirstRole() {
    return $this->roles->first();
}
```

@h2ooooooo gave this helpful link to the docs, containing all methods of the collection: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/common/2.3/class-Doctrine.Common.Collections.ArrayCollection.html

You can compare ID with an ID (integer), or string by string,
but the best is to compare Entities to keep the whole system integral:

```
public function isAdmin() {
    $role = $this->getFirstRole();

    $admin = $entityManager
       ->getRepository('User\Entity\Role')
       ->findOneByName('admin');

    if ($role === $admin) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @user3333854 Have you actually added anything to `$this->roles`?